# Qual é a diferença entre span e string_view em c++20?

Tags: c++

As duas classes fazem basicamente o mesmo, possuem um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento do array e o tamanho do array. Eu sei que `string_view` é usado para arrays de caracteres, mas não se poderia usar `span` para o mesmo?  Gostaria de saber:

- Porque a redundância?
- Quando devo usar uma ou ao invés outra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para a `std::basic_string_view`, existe todo um conjunto de métodos específicos para lidar com strings. `std::span` é para tipos genéricos, inclusive tipos definidos pelo usuário.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) para `std::basic_string_view`:

> The class template basic_string_view describes an object that can
>   refer to a constant contiguous **sequence of char-like objects**.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) para `std::span`:

> The class template span describes an object that can refer to a
>   contiguous **sequence of objects**

`std::span` descreve uma sequência de objetos sem citar algum em específico. É uma classe decorada com um template que recebe um tipo T que será o tipo do objeto usado para criar a sequência.

Quando você "especializa" `std::span` criando uma classe a parte `std::basic_string_view` você abre margem para fazer operações mais eficientes uma vez que o tipo é conhecido, além de implementar métodos pertinentes para o tipo específico.

Obs.: `std::basic_string_view` também é decorada com um template, porém é para os tipos `char`, `wchar_t`, `char8_t`, `char16_t` e `char32_t`.

Comment: Adicionalmente, `std::basic_string_view` oferece operações como [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/substr), [`starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/starts_with), [`ends_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/ends_with), [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/find) etc, que são operações comuns com strings.